# I was trying to get some document from server side using query. but I am getting the whole collection instead of matched document.Whats wrong here?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

client side code:From here I am trying to send request to the server

```
const MyItems = () => {
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
    const [myItems, setMyItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        const email = user.email;
        console.log(email);
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/products?email=${email}`;
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                setMyItems(data);
            })

    }, [user]);
```

server side code:from here i am trying to get response

```
app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
            const email = req.query.email;
            console.log(email);
            const items= { email: email };
            const cursor = productCollection.find(items);
            const result = await cursor.toArray();
            res.send(result)

        })
```

Comment: Where is __productCollection.find()__ defined?

Comment: your database seems to have duplicate entries with that email

Comment: There are 10 duplicate entries with that email,but I am still getting all entries